# google chrome app script ask to save as userAppPanel

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-script

I encounter a problem using UIApplication in google app script, but only on Chrome 18.0.1025.142 m, my application works fine on Firefox 3.6, and also on chrome 16.x.x.
I updated my chrome version to 19.0.1084.56 m. And the problem still occurs.

On Chrome 18.0.1025.142 m and 19.0.1084.56 m, I have the following behaviour:
A blank frame is displayed over my spreadsheet when I try to display the UI Application and I'm asked to perform a "Save As" operation for an object userAppPanel.

On Chrome 16.x.x or Firefox 3.6, I have a UI application with a panel, a textbox and a button.

Here is my application creation code:

```
// Create my application
  var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication();
  myapp.setTitle("Translation selector");
  // create panels, text boxes and widgets
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
  // Create input boxes and button
  var textBoxA = myapp.createTextBox();
  textBoxA.setName('Input search filter here').setId('SearchText');
  var MyButton = myapp.createButton("Fill the tables");
  mypanel.add(textBoxA);
  mypanel.add(MyButton);
  // create handler to respond to events
  var clickHandler = myapp.createServerClickHandler("respondToSubmit");
  MyButton.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(mypanel);
  // assemble everything in app
  myapp.add(mypanel);
  //mydoc.show(myapp);
  //return myapp;
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // show the app
  doc.show(myapp);

}
```

Comment: I tested your exact script on chrome Version 19.0.1084.56 and had no issue at all. Are you sure this is an exact transcript ?

Comment: Thanks @Serge for your answer, I have this behaviour on Chrome 18.X... and 19.X...
I didn't put my event code on this application, function **RespondToSubmit**.
It can be link to another interaction in my google install (perhaps with jvm or jre, I'm java developper at all!).
Don't spend more time on this problem, I will use other web browsers and hope my colleagues won't face the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I've a similar issue on Chrome 21.0.1180.89 for OSX. Working with a [mail merge script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/personalized-mail-merge-in-gmail/20981/) which worked perfectly on a, similar up-to-date, chrome on Win8 just a few hours ago.

I'm pretty sure it's a security issue.

De-authorising the app (under account->security) and then reloading the script and re-authorising it helps. Not sure if it's on a per-browser level or something else..

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Add this Code,

As per your question, It works on chrome.

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById('area').value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "ecc.plist"/*Your file name*/;

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
if (window.webkitURL != null)
{
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href =   
window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
}
else
{
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
}

downloadLink.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some users of a script I've developed, [FormEmailer](http://sites.google.com/site/formemailer) (available in the Script Gallery) that are also having this problem. But we were not able to nail the situation that generates this yet.

Is the spreadsheet you're testing yours? Or is it shared and you're not the owner? Do you have other scripts projects on this same spreadsheet? Are you the owner of all scripts?

(I think it's better if you change you edit your question and I my answer, instead of talking in the "limited" comments).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem :

More details about this after a few tests. It seems it is due both to user triggering the script to execute, as well as characteristics of the trigger :
- if the function is called from a custom menu in a spreadsheet, everything works fine for everyone
- if function is called onOpen(), everything works fine for everyone
- if an installable onEdit or onOpen trigger has been set on the function, then everything works fine for the person who set it, and bad for others.
The last behavior is observed whether that person is owner or not.

Basically it seems the only times when it doesn't work well is when someone opens or edits a spreadsheet and the function is triggered by an installable trigger installed by somebody else.

This is a pain.